# Assembling COM executables on win xp

Tags: windows, masm32

Is there a way of assembling x86 code into COM executables? I am using masm32 as my assembler. Can't find enough information on the assembling/linking command line so I always end up getting errors...

Here's a simple program and the error I get:

Any ideia? Suggestions to other assemblers with better documentation would be nice too...

Code:

> ```
>   .model tiny
>   .code
>
>   ORG 100H
> HOST:
>   mov ah, 9
>   mov dx, OFFSET HI
>   int 21H
>
>   mov ax, 4C00H
>   int 21H
>
> HI DB 'Hi$'
>
>   END HOST
> ```

Command used to assembly and Error:

> D:>ml /AT test.s  Microsoft (R) Macro
>   Assembler Version
>   6.14.8444 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.
>
> Assembling: test.s Microsoft (R)
>   Incremental Linker Version 5.12.8078
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp
>   1992-1998. All rights reserved.
>
> /z2
>   "host.obj" /t
>   "test.com"
>   NUL
>   LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "z2"; ignored
>   LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "t"; ignored
>   test.obj : warning LNK4033: converting object format from OMF to COFF
>   test.obj : fatal error LNK1190:
>   invalid fixup found, type 0x0001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include your assembly code as inline assembly into a C file, then compile it with a standard C compiler to COM.

Comment: Could suggest me one with such feature? (on windows)

Comment: I would use gcc (also on windows), but it uses AT&T syntax, so you either convert it or you look for another compiler.